# Javascript my Object is disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

My object newHomes is removed at some point when the code is ran. It can not be called from the browser console. My `console.log` inside the code does return values.

```js
$(() => {
    console.log($('#zillowLink').attr('href'))
    console.log("js is running");
    $('#addHome').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
    $('h1').addClass('text-center');

    var newHomes = [
        {address: "27569 Cedarwood Drive", sf: "2,535", bedrooms: 3, baths: 2.5, price: "$496,500"},
        {address: "316 Annandale Drive", sf: "1,326", bedrooms: 4, baths: 2, price: "$275,000"},
        {address: "251 Grandview Road", sf: "3,800", bedrooms: 3, baths: 2, price: "$699,900"},
        {address: "28571 Manitoba", sf: "2,960", bedrooms: 4, baths: 3.5, price: "$775,000"}
    ];
    console.log(newHomes);

    var cells = $('#homes thead tr').children();
    cells.eq(0).css('color', 'blue');
    cells.eq(4).css('color', 'green');

    console.log(newHomes);
    const newLink = $( '<br><br><a id="zillowLink" href="http://www.zillow.com">Visit Zillow.com<a>' );
    newLink.appendTo('body');

    console.log(newHomes);
    const addNewHome = ($event) => {
        var counter = 0;
        $($event.currentTarget).appendTo(newHomes["counter"])
    }
    console.log(newHomes);
    $('#zillowLink').attr( "target", "_blank" ); //_blank opens new Tab
    $('#addHome').on('click', 'tr', addNewHome);
    const removeHome = ($event) => {
        $($event.currentTarget).fadeOut(
            500, ()=>{
                this.remove
            });
    }
    console.log(newHomes);
    $('#homes tbody').on('click', 'tr', removeHome);

    console.log(newHomes);
   


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome Back to jQuery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body class="container">

    <h1 class="jumbotron">Lake Arrowhead Homes For Sale</h1>

    <table id="homes" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Sq. Ft.</th>
                <th>Bedrooms</th>
                <th>Baths</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>27374 Matterhorn Drive</td>
                <td>1,664</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>$279,500</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>243 El Dorado</td>
                <td>4,900</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>6.5</td>
                <td>$990,000</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1228 Klondike Drive</td>
                <td>2,158</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>2.5</td>
                <td>$400,000</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button id="addHome" class="btn btn-danger">Add Home</button>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access the `newHomes` variable from the console level, as it is defined in the local scope of Your immiediately-invoked function. That means `newHomes` is valid in the context of the function, but it doesn't exist outside of it. You need to expose it. For instance:

```
var foo = function() {
  this.a = 1;
  var b = 2;
}
```

If You paste this code in Your browser's console and execute `foo()`, accessing `a` will give You `1`, but accessing `b` will result in `ReferenceError: b is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

Pull your variable outside the IIFE. So, pull **var newHomes** out of your function and place it above your function.  Having it outside changes the scope so you can access it outside the function.